# Parsing for Column Headings in Excel worksheet with Python

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison

I have an Excel spreadsheet which looks like this:

```
Row1 :           some text
some other row : "ABC Col" "DEF Col" "GHI Col" "JKL Col"
following rows : more text
```

I am trying to find the row that contains ABC and JKL. Note the string that I am passing may not match the exact column heading.

I am using `xlrd` and am doing something like this:

```
setOfheadings = set(['ABC', 'JKL'])
found_header = False
for i in range(1,sheet.nrows):
    if ((not found_header)):
        setOfRowValues = set([element.upper() for element in sheet.row_values(i)])
        if len(setOfheadings.intersection(setOfRowValues)) == len(setOfheadings):
            (found_header, header_row) = (True,i)
```

Since 'ABC' does not exactly match 'ABC Col' in the spreadsheet. It fails. It works if my `setOfheadings` contains the exact match.

Any ideas on how I can do a regex match with set intersection?

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with `Excel` or `xlrd`; tags removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it. Features: Factors out the definition of inexact match from the code that iterates over columns and rows. Avoids a crash on non-text data. Bales out when it's found the presumably-desired row.

```
targets = ('ABC', 'JKL')

def fuzzy_match(target, some_text):
    return target in some_text # or something fancier

found_header = False    
for i in xrange(1, sheet.nrows):
    row_text = [
        v.upper()
        for v, t in zip(sheet.row_values(i), sheet.row_types(i))
        if t == xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT # avoid non-text cells; see note below
        ]
    found_header = all(
        any(fuzzy_match(target, item) for item in row_text)
        for target in targets
        )
    if found_header:
        header_row = i
        break
```

The code that avoids non-text cells is xlrd-specific; a more general way of doing it would 
be:

```
for v in sheet.row_values(i)
if isinstance(v, basestring)
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is related to [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), one of the toughest subjects in CS. Python has powerful module devoted to NLP stuff called [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Natural Language Toolkit).

One way to do it is computing the distance from what you want to what you get using some algorithm like [n-gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram), but every time you make this sort of fuzzy comparisons, you risk getting false positives.